# Windows Phone 8 Push Notification

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-runtime, push-notification, windows-phone-8, mpns

The structure of PUSH Notification for Windows Store 8 App differs from Windows Phone 8 app (in terms of Registration, Authentication, etc,.) at least that's what I gather from the two below links.

1. [Windows Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx).
2. [Windows Phone 8.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

   I decided to run the sample from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202967%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). I downloaded it, ran it and waited for URI to return, but nothing happens. No response at all.  I am using Visual Studio 2012.

   1. What is the mistake that I am making here?
   2. Why is there a different approach for Windows Store 8 application and Windows Phone 8 PUSH notification service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your were asking in question #1.

Overall Win8 and WP8 push notifications are different because they end up supporting different UX on the operating system itself. Win8 and WP8 need different data to power their tiles, toast notifications and raw channels. As a result of that you'll need different message formats to power each platform. And as a result of that the services were separated for MPNS (Microsoft Push Notifications Service) on WP8 and WPNS (Windows Push Notifications Services) on Win8.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, i guess i might know the problem with the first question.

Comment: I guess Access to MPNS from my LAN is blocked ( Hence No URI response, notting at all ), How do  get the Service address to put it in Access list?